# Performance impact of moving 132 .htaccess files to httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a 132 `.htaccess` files under different directories. There are 1400 lines in all these files combined, most of which are `mod_rewrite` rules. I was thinking of moving the rules to the `httpd.conf` file, so that the `AllowOverride all` directive can be disabled.

I have two options for placing the rules within the httpd.conf.

- Place it directly under the `<VirtualHost>` section
- Place each file content under seperate `<Directory>` section, with `directory-path` corresponding to the `.htaccess` file location

Which of the above methods will have a better performance?

The rewrite rules are all regex patterns, so I cannot replace them with single rule with DB mapping. Over 80% of the rules are like

```
RewriteRule ^/dir/([a-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).html$ file.php?someparam=$1&anotherparam=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/dir/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ file.php?someparam=$1&anotherparam=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: It depends a lot on what kind of rules you have to know if using it directly or indirectly would impact the performance. But you could easily test it.

Comment: If most rules are the same you can certainly find a way to write it once for all, check also `RewriteMap` which is only available outside of `.htaccess`. You're on the right way.